# Django: {{STATIC_URL}} tag not working when url path is extended

Tags: python, django, url, django-templates

I'm using `{{STATIC_URL}}` all over the place in my templates (for simplification, we'll used the homepage as an example). So, I've got a parent template called "home_base.html", which uses the tag in situations like this:

```
<script src="{{STATIC_URL}}js/plugins.js">
<img src={{STATIC_URL}}img/blah.jpg>
```

In my urls.py file, I've got two urls, *that point to the same view*:

```
url(r'^home/$', 'homepage.views.HomeView'),
url(r'^home/x/$', 'homepage.views.HomeView', {'x': '3'}),
```

When I visit mysite.com/home, everything works fine. However, when I visit mysite.com/home/x, none of the files in the static folder of the app can be found. I get errors that look like this, for each static file in the template:

```
[30/Jan/2013 13:04:20] "GET /homepage/static/js/plugins_functions.js HTTP/1.1" 404 7325
[30/Jan/2013 13:04:20] "GET /homepage/static/js/backb_global.js HTTP/1.1" 404 7310
```

It seems like it's adding `/homepage/` to the beginning...usually it gets `/static/js...`

**I have found that it has something to do with adding stuff to the url path**, because if I change my urls to look like this, everything works perfectly:

```
url(r'^home/$', 'homepage.views.HomeView'),
url(r'^x/$', 'homepage.views.HomeView', {'x': '3'}),
```

---

Why does everything get messed up when I add slashes to the url? How can I fix it? I would really like to just add things to home like this: `url(r'^home/add/stuff/to/address/$'`, and still have all the `{{STATIC_URL}}` tags working.

Keep in mind that I'm using this parent template as a base for many other templates, so it's important for me that I can add to the path of the url, and keep the `{{STATIC_URL}}` tags in the home_base.html file.

Comment: can you show the definition of STATIC_URL? Seems like you have used a relative path...

Comment: `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`

Answer (score 0):

Try to escape the string variable with

```
{{STATIC_URL|safe}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/ where it says:

> If {{ STATIC_URL }} isn't working in your template, you're probably not using RequestContext when rendering the template.

and:

> make sure 'django.core.context_processors.static' is in your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS.

Comment: I am using RequestContext when rendering the template from the view (as is proven by the fact that both urls are calling the same exact view, and one of them works perfectly). TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS is good as well. Any other ideas?